# How to display bytes of pcap file (payload) using scapy and discard ASCII values

Tags: python, byte, wireshark, scapy, pcap

I am reading a pcap file and I want to extract the payload of a pcap file using scapy. When I extract the info, I get it in ASCII format and not in bytes.For example: In a pcap file containing 100 packets, I extract the payload of the third packet.

```
pcap[2].load
```

This gives me the result:

```
b'Beacon-v2|JCK|WindowsPC|03cde3a22ae9a70bb8c5137fa482a4e39888ebbc\nOpenSensor-v2|62190\n'
```

Although, I want just the bytes [hex format] and not the ASCII characters. I want the hex format corresponding to that which is (42 65 61 6f and so on)

```
0000   42 65 61 63 6f 6e 2d 76 32 7c 4a 43 4b 7c 57 69   Beacon-v2|JCK|Wi
0010   6e 64 6f 77 73 50 43 7c 30 33 63 64 65 33 61 32   ndowsPC|03cde3a2
0020   32 61 65 39 61 37 30 62 62 38 63 35 31 33 37 66   2ae9a70bb8c5137f
0030   61 34 38 32 61 34 65 33 39 38 38 38 65 62 62 63   a482a4e39888ebbc
0040   0a 4f 70 65 6e 53 65 6e 73 6f 72 2d 76 32 7c 36   .OpenSensor-v2|6
0050   32 31 39 30 0a                                    2190.
```

I have tried using:

```
bytes(pcap[2].load)

hexdump(pcap[2].load)

bytearray(pcap[2].load)

raw(pcap[2].payload)
```

It would be a great help if you could help me display this load in bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Suffix `b` means that value you received is bytestring (`bytes`). If you want to print it as hex you can use [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify): `hexlify(pcap[2].load, sep=" ")`.

Comment: To print it "nice" you can save result to variable: `res = pcap[2].load` and convert every 16 bytes separately: `print(*(hexlify(res[i: i + 16], sep=" ") for i in range(0, len(res), 16)), sep="\n")`

Comment: Many thanks! This was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments you can use the [hexlify function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) from the [binascii module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html).

```
from binascii import hexlify
res = pcap[2].load 
print(*(hexlify(res[i: i + 16], sep=" ") for i in range(0, len(res), 16)), sep="\n")
```